# How to determine no active child threads before closing application?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am writing a program which is suppose to send emails to various email IDs [about 10000] at a time classified in a various categories.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WaitHandle[] waitHandles = new WaitHandle[]
    {
        new AutoResetEvent(false),
        new AutoResetEvent(false),
        new AutoResetEvent(false),
        new AutoResetEvent(false)
    };

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(p.SendMailToCart), waitHandles[0]);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(p.SendScheduled), waitHandles[1]);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(p.Mailer), waitHandles[2]);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(p.BookReviewMail), waitHandles[3]);

    .....
    .....
}
```

After this, I should use .WaitAll as:

```
WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles);
```

And, from the methods I am calling in different thread, I need to call .Set() Method and inform that the execution has finished. As..

```
AutoResetEvent waitHandle = (AutoResetEvent) obj;
waitHandle.Set();
```

But the problem is:
I have Four different method which I call on separate threads each, and in each method there are another new threads, my code is like:

```
foreach(DataRow dr in dtEmails.Rows)
{
    Thread sendMail = new Thread(delegate()
    {
        string _emailBody = CreateEmails.CreateEmail();
        if (_emailBody.Length > 0)
        {
            bool result = SendEmail.SendMail(SubjectLine(_subjectline), userID, _emailBody);
            if (result == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("> Email sent to {0}", userID);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("> Email sending failed for {0}.", userID);
            }
        }
    });
    sendMail.Start();
    sendMail.IsBackground = true;
}
```

dtEmails (DataTable may contains up to 10000 Rows.)

So, I am not getting the point how to use

```
AutoResetEvent waitHandle = (AutoResetEvent) obj;
waitHandle.Set();
```

For the solution to this problem I have find a temporary code:

```
WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles);
```

[REPLACED WITH]

```
while (true)
{
    if (ThreadCounter() <= 1)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000 * 30);
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
    Thread.Sleep(1000 * 30);
}
```

But as we know

```
Thread.Sleep();
```

wastes CPU time, I need a better solution.
I have found many solution on Google but they are not exactly what I need.

**EDIT**: I am using SMTP to send emails.

Comment: Please format your code, as it is currently unreadable. You're queueing work on a threadpool thread, but inside the given delegate you instantiate another thread, and all this to do async IO. There isn't a need to actually generate so many threads. What protocol are you using to send mail?

Comment: Which .NET framework version are you using?

Comment: I am using .NET Framework 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending an e-mail over the wire is an IO operation. Such as, we can take advantage of using async API's offered by `SmtpClient`. This way, we have no need to generate any threads which will simply block until the request finishes.

To do this, we'll use [`SmtpClient.SendMailAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194001(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public async Task SendMailsAsync()
{
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     var mailTasks = dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(mail => 
     {
        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        return smtpClient.SendMailAsync(new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body));
     }).ToArray();

     await Task.WhenAll(mailTasks);
}
```

This method uses the `async-await` and the Task Asynchronous Pattern. This way, you don't execute any redundant threadpool threads, and you gain the benefit of async IO.
You can get started [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).

Comment: Using `SmtpClient.SendMailAsync` is really good in context of sending emails.
What should i do as required to call Four Different Method right from the Main() Mathod.

Comment: What do these methods do? Do they simply send the mail? I would concat them into one method which sends all mail.

Comment: Yes All of them do the same task but the data source are separate.

Comment: Then query all the data sources from all the different places, aggregate them and execute.